# validate the entry of an ASCII character

Tags: c, char, ascii

I have a homework problem.  I have to validate the entry of uppercase characters, but am having a problem with the A to Z.

I just put a `while (c<65 || c>90)` and it works fine. But, in my country we, use `Ñ` too, so that is my problem. I tried to use the ascii code 165 to validate the entry but it didn't work.

The char range is from -128 to 127, so for the extended ASCII table I need an unsigned char right?

i tried this:

```
int main (){
    unsinged char n;

    //scanf("%c",&n);
    printf("%c",n);
    return 0;
}
```

Print the 165 if it scans a 'Ñ'.

The next one:

```
unsigned char n;
n='Ñ';
printf("%d",n);
```

pPrints 209.

So I try to validate with 165 and 209 and neither works.

Why does this happen?  What can I do to validate the entry of this character?

---

its works when i use `unsigned char` and validate with 165. But when i used cmd to try it by reading a txt file, didn't work...

Comment: `n='Ñ';` may not work, the character set used in your program source may be different to the character set used when you are entering characters at runtime.

Comment: @user9000 He's not using unicode.

Comment: U+00D1 : `D1` is `209`

Comment: The [Windows-1252](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows-1252) codec uses 209(D1h) for `Ñ`, and [code page 437](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_page_437) uses 165(A5h) suggesting the OP is on a Windows system.  The source code is probably using the default `Windows-1252` code page, but running it in a console window will use the OEM `cp437` code page.  To understand the situation, try: http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html

Comment: @MattMcNabb The UTF-8 `Ñ` bytes for are `0xC3 0x91`.  The fact that he sees `209` suggests that he is _NOT_ using UTF-8 input locale.

Comment: @MooingDuck: Observe the following table: (UTF-8 initial char table)[http://www.utf8-chartable.de/unicode-utf8-table.pl?unicodeinhtml=dec]. If you are reading and writting files that only use these characters (U+0000 to U+00FF), then every character will be encoded in UTF-8 with exactly 1 byte, and the 1-byte number 209 will correspond to `'Ñ'`.

Comment: @pablo1977: I see your table, but it doesn't match what you say.  The characters U+0000 to __U+007F__ then each character will be encoded in UTF-8 with exactly 1 byte (see table).  Each byte can only hold 0x00 to 0xFF, if all of those were single byte characters, then all other characters would be impossible to uniquely encode.  Additionally, the chart _explicitly_ says that the UTF-8 hex for `Ñ` U+00D1 is "`c3 91`".

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> print the 165 if i scan a 'Ñ'.

- This means that in your system the character 'Ñ' has code equal to 165, as in the usual extension **ISO 8859-1** extension of ASCII.

  ```
  printf("%d",'Ñ');
  ```

> print 209.

- This reveals a different encoding for the characters you enter manually in your IDE.
  **Mark Tolonen** has suggested that it corresponds to **OEM cp437**.
  (I originally associated to **UTF-8** by I'm a little confused now...)

IN **C** you have to take in account the existence of two collating sequence for characters, that could be different:

1. The **source character set**.
2. The **execution character set**.

The source character set is referred to the encoding used by your editing environment, that is, the place where you normally type your **.c** files. Your system and/or editor and/or IDE is working with a specific encoding-schema. In this case, it seems that the encoding is UTF-8.

Thus, if you write 'Ñ' in your editor, the character Ñ has the encoding of your editor, and has not the encoding of the target system. In this case you have Ñ encoded as 209, which gives you `'Ñ' == 209` as true.

The execution character set is referred to the encoding using in the operative system and/or the console you are using to run your executable (that is, compiled) programs. It seems clear that the encoding is **Latin 1** (ISO-8859-1).

In particular, when you type Ñ in the console of your system, it's encoded as 165, which gives you the value 165 when you print the value.

Since this dichotomy always can happen (or not), you must be warried about that, and make some adjustments, to avoid potential problems.

> its works when i use unsigned char and validate with 165. But when i used cmd to try it by reading a txt file, didn't work...

- This means that your **.txt** file has been written with a text editor (perhaps your own IDE, I guess), that is using an encoding different to **Latin 1** (ISO-8859-1).

**Let me guess:** You are writting your C code and your text files with the same IDE, but you are executing programs from the Windows CMD.

There are two possible solutions here.

The complicated solution is that you investigate about **encoding schemas**, **locale issues**, and **wide characters**. There is not quick solutions here, because it needs to be careful about several delicate stuff.

The easy solution is to make adjustments in all the tools you are using.

1. Go to the options of your IDE and try to obtain the information of the encoding schema used to save text files (I guessed you have UTF-8, but you can have there other possibilities, like LATIN 1 (or ISO-8859-1), UTF-16 and a large etc.):
2. Execute in your CMD the command **CHCP** to obtain the **codepage number** that your system is using. This **codepage** is a number whose meaning is explained my **Microsoft**, here:

   a. [OEM codepages](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/goglobal/bb964655)
     b. [Windows codepages](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/goglobal/bb964654)
     c. [ISO codepages](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/goglobal/cc305167)
     d. [LIST OF ALL WINDOWS CODEPAGES](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd317756(v=vs.85).aspx)

   I guess you have codepage 850 or well 28591 (corresponding to **Latin 1**).
3. Change one of these configurations to fit with the other one.

   a. In the configuration of your IDE, in the "editor options" part, you could change the encoding to something like **Latin 1**, or **ISO-8859-1**.

   b. Or well, better change the codepage in your CMD, by means of the **CHCP** command, to fit **OEM 437** encoding:

   CHCP 437

Probably the solution involving the change of **codepage** in CMD not always work as one expected.
It's safer the solution (a.): to modify the configuration of your editor.
However, it would be prefirable to keep the **UTF-8** in your editor (if this is your editor's choice), because nowadays every modern software is turning to **UTF** encodings (**Unicode**).

**New info:** The **UTF-8** encoding sometimes uses more than 1 byte to represent 1 character. The following table shows the UTF-8 encoding for the first 256 entry points:

- [UTF-8 for U+0000 to U+00FF](http://www.utf8-chartable.de/unicode-utf8-table.pl?unicodeinhtml=dec)

**Note:** After a little discussion in the comments, I realized that I had some wrong believes about **UTF-8** encoding. At least, this illustrate my point: **encoding** is not a trivial matter.

So, I have to repeat here my advice to the OP: go by the simplest path and try to achieve to an agreement with your teacher about how to handle encoding for special characters.

Comment: but this solution will make it work in my computer, but the teacher use his own txt file to try the code. Anyways, thanks for the information.

Comment: @exsnake The text must be in an agreed upon encoding, either a specified one or the OS default for your common culture. You should write your program so it works with a specific encoding or adapts to the settings of the user that runs the program.

Comment: @exsnake: I understand your problem, but you have to understand that the issue of character encodings is not easy. It involves strong computational experience. So, if you're starting to program (as you are talking about "your teacher"), then you have to accept handy and temporary solutions. The best advice that I can give you, then, is that you **talk to your teacher** and explain him **the problems you have with encodings**, in then, you and him will go togegher to a convenient and practical solution, because it seems obvious that character encoding isn't the main topic in your class.

Comment: "every special character (as Ñ Ç Á É Í Ó Ú Ü ñ ç á é í ó ú ü) can be encoded by using only 1 byte. I"  That is 100% dead wrong for UTF-8.  See the "UTF-8 (hex.)" column of this table: http://www.utf8-chartable.de/unicode-utf8-table.pl?unicodeinhtml=dec]

Comment: @MooingDuck: You are right. My answer is totally wrong. I will delete it soon.

Comment: @pablo1977: Wait what?  This answer is otherwise quite excellent.  The only errors are the two paragraphs that say UTF-8.  He's actually using a different encoding. Mark Tolonen suggests maybe "OEM cp437".  Just fix the references to UTF-8.

Comment: @MooingDuck: Well, then I will delete the last paragraph. I am sorry by the mistakes.

Comment: @MooingDuck: I have rewritten some parts of the answer, taking in account my mistakes about UTF-8. Perhaps the answer shows a bit of my ouwn confusion now. I hope it be still good enough.

Comment: I think it's not a good answer from your teacher. To validate the scanned character from Windows CMD you have the encoding ISo-8859-1 (codepage 850), which is different from the encoding used by your text editor. In reading text files, very probably you have another 1-byte encoding (not Unicode), which Microsoft calls **Windows 1252**. (I follow in the next message...)

Comment: (...) Now, the characters with hexa codes from 0xC0 to 0xFF have the same number as the entry points in the Unicode table. This is the reason why you can use that table in this particular case. Look down of the following table: [Windows C.P. 1252](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/goglobal/cc305145), and compare the values of Unicode and Windows 1252 from 0x00C0 to 0x00FF. They are the same. However, the Unicode table has much more than 256 entry points, it's this: [Unicode table](http://unicode-table.com/en/). I think the table you can trust is the former: **Windows 1252**. Use it and tell me.

Comment: @pablo1977 thanks for evryting, i was doing some test and i discovered this: When you enter the Ñ in the executable the program prints 165, but in cmd the program prints 209. When you put cchar=Ñ; in the code and print "cchar" the executable an CMD prints 209.. So i make this code:

Comment: int main()
{
    unsigned char key,code;
    code='Ñ';
    scanf("%c",&key);
    printf("\n%c",key);
    if(key=code || key==165)
        printf("\nworks");
    return 0;
}

Comment: and works fine in cmd and direct in the exe, but... is a valid way to solve this problem?

Comment: Your condition `key=code` is always true, because it's an assignment (so, it's wrong). I think your approach is not good. You need to consider two different encodings in the same program: one for CMD input and another one for text file input or well output. In validating cmd input I only would use `if(key == 165)`. Under other circumstances, I would use `if(key == code)`. It depends on the context, or what are you doing in a specific situation. Besides: use `#defined` constants instead of magic numbers like **165**.

Comment: yeah i noticed the "=" sorry for the mistake, i fixed it. I'm using it to read only uppercase characters from an scanf, i used a while((ch<65 || ch>90) && (ch!=code) && (ch!=165)) and works fine until now. gonna use a #defined for the 65, 90 and 165 as you said, thanks you!.

Answer (score 2):

`165` is not an ASCII code. ASCII goes from 0 to 127.  165 is a code in some other character set. In any case, `char` must be used for `scanf` and you can convert the value to `unsigned char` after that. Alternatively, use `getchar()` which returns a value in the range of `unsigned char` already.

You should use the standard function `isalpha` from `ctype.h`:

```
int n = getchar();
if ( isalpha(n) )
{
    // do something...
}
```

You probably also will have to set a locale in which this character is a letter, e.g. `setlocale( LC_CTYPE, "es_ES");`

Comment: @Dan it also depends on the compiler/library actually supporting locale properly, which I don't have a huge confidence in

Comment: If it works, your teacher might give you extra points for using that library. It shows good research.

Comment: I didn't say "extended" in my answer. Adjusted.